# Gaps in email template in Yahoo Mail

Tags: html, html-email

I am having a bit of trouble with a gap that appears only in IE (any version) and Yahoo Mail.  I trying to create an email template with tables (with one nested table).  As you can see in the image, there is a gap at the top and bottom of a TD that houses the header.  If I try and view the HTML locally, I don't see the problem in IE so it's when it's inn Yahoo Mail that the issue is present.  Other mail clients is fine.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Screenshot of issue:
[image: Screenshot of issue]

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Email Template</title>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        body {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }
        table {
            margin:15px auto 50px auto;
        }
        td hr {
            padding:0;
            margin:10px;
            background-color:rgb(0,13,221);
            height:1px;
            border:0;
        }
        td {
            font-size:12px;
        }
        td p {
            padding-top:7px;
        }
        td p a {
            color:rgb(0,134,195);
        }
        td strong {
            font-size:13px;
            font-weight:900;
            color:rgb(0,0,0);
        }
        .address {
            margin-top:50px !important; !important;
            font-size:11px;
            color:rgb(79,83,87);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="690" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="5" width="20" valign="top">
                <img src="#" width="25" height="538" style="background-color:blue;display:block" />
            </td>
            <td width="650">
                <table width="650" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="650" height="19" colspan="3" style="background-color:rgb(10,14,43)"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(10,13,44)">
                            <td height="1" width="3%"></td>
                            <td rowspan="49" width="7%">
                                <img src="#" width="192" height="72" style="background-color:blue;display:block" />
                            </td>
                            <td width="90%"></td>                               
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(12,15,46)">
                            <td height="3"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(13,16,47)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(12,15,46)">
                            <td height="2"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(13,16,47)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(12,17,47)">
                            <td height="2"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(12,17,49)">
                            <td height="5"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(13,18,50)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(12,17,49)">
                            <td height="2"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(13,18,50)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(12,18,50)">
                            <td height="2"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(10,19,52)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(11,20,53)">
                            <td height="2"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(12,21,54)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(11,20,53)">
                            <td height="2"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(12,21,54)">
                            <td height="2"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(13,22,55)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(12,23,55)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(11,22,54)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(13,23,58)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(13,21,57)">
                            <td height="4"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(12,22,57)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(10,23,58)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(10,24,59)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(14,24,60)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(12,25,60)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(11,24,59)">
                            <td height="2"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(12,25,60)">
                            <td height="3"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(12,26,61)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(12,25,60)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(13,25,63)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(14,26,64)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(12,26,63)">
                            <td height="2"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(13,27,64)">
                            <td height="2"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(13,27,66)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(15,27,67)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(13,27,66)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(12,27,66)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(10,28,66)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(11,29,69)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(12,30,70)">
                            <td height="2"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(14,29,70)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(11,30,72)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(12,29,72)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(13,30,73)">
                            <td height="3"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(13,32,75)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(10,31,74)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:rgb(9,32,74)">
                            <td height="1"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="650" height="2" colspan="3" style="background-color:rgb(10,31,74)"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="650" height="1" colspan="3" style="background-color:rgb(11,32,77)"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="650" height="2" colspan="3" style="background-color:rgb(11,34,78)"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="650" height="1" colspan="3" style="background-color:rgb(13,34,79)"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="650" height="1" colspan="3" style="background-color:rgb(12,35,79)"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="5" width="20" valign="top"><img src="#" width="25" height="538" style="background-color:blue;display:block" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="650" valign="top">
                <img src="#" width="650" height="10" style="background-color:blue;display:block" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:0 10px 0 10px">
                <p><strong>Headline</strong></p>
                <p>Text Line 1</p>
                <p>Text Line 2</p>
                <p>Text Line 3 <a href="#"> Link</a></p>
                <p>Text Line 4</p>  
                <p></p>
                <hr />
                <p>Text Line 5</p>
                <p style="margin-top:80px;font-size:11px;color:rgb(65,65,65);" class="address">Text Line 6</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><img src="#" width="626" height="68" style="background-color:blue;display:block" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><p>Text Line 7<a href="#">Link</a></p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test the email in any email clients BUT, i did find the problem occurring in firefox. Using firebug i corrected the problem by adding vertical-align:top on line 20 (the td style)

Just be aware that you may need to use inline styles as some email clients strip out stylesheets whether in the head or body of the document.

Here is a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/ypzA2/